# How to convert t.co URLs to Big URLs?

Tags: r, curl, get, sapply, httr

I am trying to understand how to convert t.co URLs to big URLs?

I have a dataset of 7,175 t.co URLs. I kind of know how to convert single URLs to big URLs (using `httr::GET`). However, when it comes to 7,175 URLs, I should use `sapply` to apply the `Get` function over all URLs (in R this can be done by `httr` package).

For example, assume that my dataset's name is "urls_common" with two variables: source_url (which contains t.co urls), and count of each url. I use the following set of codes to convert t.co to big URLs.

```
urls <- t(sapply(urls_common$source_url, GET)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(urls, status_code)
```

But I get different errors, such as:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>     Failed to connect to jamaica-gleaner.com port 80: Connection refused

OR

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>     Empty reply from server

When I run the above codes on smaller datasets (e.g., the first or second or third 500 t.co URLs), it sometimes works well for some datasets, and sometimes gets the following errors:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>     Could not resolve host: my-news-feed.com
>
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>     SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
>
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>     Could not resolve host: experience.safety

I would appreciate if you could help me get this error fixed.

Comment: A few thoughts: 1. I recommend using `lapply` instead of `t(sapply(...))` as the structure of the output for this task will be arguably clearer. 2. Have you tested the links yielding errors? (You can do a simple loop and see which are the problematic ones) 3. The internet is quite a mess, so you may wrap your `GET` inside a `try` for safety. 4. A small note: 8000 URL's is quite something especially if the responses are heavy. So you might want to consider splitting the work.

Comment: If you are just looking for the URL (and not the actual content), use HEAD instead of GET. This will give you the header information including the redirected URL but potentially drastically reduce the data returned as it skips the actual content at the URL.